# I Can read all PLC outputs and inputs.... But i can't change PLC output by pyads

Tags: python, twincat

How to change the twincat plc output through pyads...

```
import pyads


plc = pyads.Connection('192.168.102.229.1.1', 801)

plc.open()


vacuum_21 = plc.read_by_name('.O_Vakuum_Wafer_21_EIN',pyads.PLCTYPE_USINT)

print("Vacuum 21 : " + str(vacuum_21))


plc.write_by_name('.O_Vakuum_Wafer_21_EIN', 0 ,pyads.PLCTYPE_USINT)


vacuum_21 = plc.read_by_name('.O_Vakuum_Wafer_21_EIN',pyads.PLCTYPE_USINT)

print("Vacuum 21 : " + str(vacuum_21))


plc.close()
```

RESTART: C:\Users\Operator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37- 
32\twincat_trial.py

Vaccum 21 : 1

Vaccum 21 : 1

Answer (score 0):

Because the output gets probably overwritten by the plc.

Comment: Was this the problem?